# regexp counter с помощью текстового редактора

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

задача в следующем,
есть некий текст

```
g1
g1
g1
g1
g1
```

нужно с помощью regexp превратить этот текст в следующий

```
g1
g2
g3
g4
g5
```

Как это сделать с помощью np++ в разделе поиск и замена